Python: "for" & "while" loops in one line
this is probably a trivial question, but I am using Python and I am struggling to type a "for" and "while" loop in the same line. I would appreciate a convenient way to do this. Thanks.
I tried the following example in my computer terminal; notice the error:
>>> for i in range(10):
...     count = 0
...     while count < 1:
...             print(count)
...             count += 1
... 
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
>>> for i in range(10): count = 0; while count < 1: print(count); count += 1
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    for i in range(10): count = 0; while count < 1: print(count); count += 1
                                   ^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>


Why would you do that? this is not trivial at all, it seems like a bad idea.

You'll find Getting started useful when trying to understand Python syntax

Why? Python doesn't care how many lines of code you use. All fancy one-liners do is piss off people who have to maintain code you've written

One of the stated design goals when Python was created, was that it should be easy to not only write, but also to read. Cramming multiple statements onto a single line goes against that.

Besides that, the issue is more about scoping I would guess. The Python parser forbids it because it's impossible to know the scope of each statement.

first of all, why?
second: python uses indentation to determine scopes, how would you differentiate
for i in range(10):
    count = 0
    while count < 1:
        print(count)
        count += 1

from
for i in range(10):
    count = 0
    while count < 1:
        print(count)
    count += 1

one will end, the other won't
edit: if you absolutely have to
 (lambda count=0: None if [(count:=0,[[print(count),count := count+1] for _ in range(10) if count<1]) for i in range(10)] else None)()

but don't do this, this shit's unreadable at best
another edit: at least fixing the mess above the best i can but still limited with no use of "while"

thank you for your answer, I understand the problem. The reason why I want the one line is that in my case I need to include the whole script in an exec("...") command (long story why). Let me ask another question then: how would you write my example as multiple lines in the exec("...")?

ok, first off, the last lambda thing has a small mistake with count being set to 0 every loop in your code, anyway use multline strings (thee quotes your multiline code another three quotes) then run that in exec

or you can write it to a .py file import it (which runs it) then reload the module when you need to run it again (even if new code is written)
